# How to loop through $_GET to get all the data

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

I've a big problem:
When someone selects multiple products, for example he selects 3 products, it goes into the shopping cart. When he sends the order (checkout) I only see the first product in my mail, not 3.

This is because I have stated in function.js:

```
function fillInForm(){

    NumberOrdered = 0;
    NumberOrdered = readCookies("NumberOrdered");

    for (i = 1; i <= NumberOrdered; i++){
        NewOrder = "Order" + i;
        thisCookie = "";
        thisCookie = readCookies(NewOrder);;
        fields = new Array();
        fields = thisCookie.split("|");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Product ID " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[0] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Brand " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[1] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Model " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[2] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Price " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[3] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Amount products " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[4] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Total cost " + i + "\" value=\"" + fields[3] * fields[4] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\" " + "\" value=\"" + "\">");

    }
}
```

when I use var_dump($_GET); it shows me everything, so the three products it shows me have 
something like

```
["Brand_1"]=>
["Brand_2"]=>
["Brand_3"]=>
```

In mail.php where the information is send to I have:

```
$brand = $_GET["Brand_1"]; (<<WITH 1, one)
```

because

```
$brand = $_GET["Brand_i"]; (<<WITH i) does not work.
```

But in theory I need

```
$brand = $_GET["Brand_i"] (<<WITH i)to get all the products............
```

How can I fix this?

mail.php

```
$productid = $_GET["Product_ID_1"];
$brand = $_GET["Brand_1"];
$model = $_GET["Model_1"];
$price = $_GET["Price_1"];
$amount = $_GET["Amount_products_1"];
$totalcost = $_GET["Total_cost_1"];

$message .= 'Your order information: ' . '<br />';
$message .= 'Product ID: ' . $productid . "<br />" .
            'Brand: '. $brand . "<br />" .
            'Model: ' . $model . "<br />" .
            'Price per item: ' . $price . "<br />" .
            'Amount of item: ' . $amount . "<br />" .
            'Total cost: ' . $totalcost . "<br />" .
            'Order date and time: ' . $date;
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: please be clear about `In mail.php where the information is send to I have: $brand = $_GET["Brand_1"]; (<$brand = $_GET["Brand_i"]; (<$_GET["Brand_i"] (<`

Comment: Try this $model = $_GET["Model1"]; instead of $model = $_GET["Model_1"]; because when u create a form , name of the field doesnot have "_"

Comment: Then I get Undefined index: Brand1 when I want to send the mail

Comment: try to use brand[] as name for hidden element, and  `foreach ($_POST['brand'] as $key => $value) {
  echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br>";
 }`

Comment: try removing the spaces in the names, and match them to the mail.php file

Comment: ps.don't forget that adding price etc to hidden fields is never smart, because hidden fields are editable..

Comment: @Luceos I will keep that in mind, this is for learning purposes and maybe for future plans. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message .= 'Your order information: ' . '<br />';
$i = 1;
while (isset($_GET["Product_ID_".$i])) {
    $productid = $_GET["Product_ID_".$i];
    $brand = $_GET["Brand_".$i];
    $model = $_GET["Model_".$i];
    $price = $_GET["Price_".$i];
    $amount = $_GET["Amount_products_".$i];
    $totalcost = $_GET["Total_cost_".$i];

    $message .= 'Product ID: ' . $productid . "<br />" .
                'Brand: '. $brand . "<br />" .
                'Model: ' . $model . "<br />" .
                'Price per item: ' . $price . "<br />" .
                'Amount of item: ' . $amount . "<br />" .
                'Total cost: ' . $totalcost . "<br />" .
    $i++;
}

$message .= 'Order date and time: ' . $date;
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: This assumes there will always be 3 items. This will probably not always be the case.

Comment: yes, You are right, that was to show off the error but I guess the loop should be a better choice

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you ask her?

Comment: Well, numberordered has to be NumberOrdered. But it does not work. I get Undefined variable:

Comment: @F4LLCON this is because you didn't pass it to the php, let me change a little thing

Comment: Aaaaaand... Sir, you are amazing, it works! -but- .... I now get Undefined variable: productid in mail.php on line 66 I will add this to the question so you can see what is there

Comment: @Sebas No harm. I wasn't offended. Sarcasm is difficult to identify over the internet.

Comment: @Sebas nevermind, I will delete productid in that table, it has no use anyways. Well Sir, thank you! it works now! :D

Comment: this is because in your html there is: `name=\"Product ID " + i + "\"`, replace it with `name=\"Product_ID_" + i + "\"`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably something like

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_GET['numberordered']; $i++)
{
    $brand = $_GET['Brand_'.$i];
    // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

You need a loop to iterate through them, you can't just use `Brand_i`

Answer (score 1):

<del>To clarify, spaces and underscores are not interchangeable. If you have this field:</del>

```
<input type="hidden" name="brand 1" />
```

<del>Then to access it on the server you have to use `$_GET['brand 1']` and not `$_GET['brand_1']`.</del>

As *@GlitchMr* pointed out, apparently spaces in field names are converted into underscores by PHP. I wasn't aware of this functionality. What you have now is fine, but I would strongly recommend against using spaces in the first place.

You also cannot use `i` inside a string an assume PHP will understand that there are multiple things and it should substitute numbers in for `i`. Indicate that the field is an array by naming the inputs in the HTML like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="brand[]" />
```

Then, you don't have to worry about numbering them with Javascript. PHP will understand that this is an array of values and:

```
print_r($_GET['brand[]']);
```

Will be an array that you can iterate through with foreach to compose the email that needs to be sent.

```
$length = count($_GET['brand']);
$fields = array('product_id[]', 'model[]', 'price[]', 'amount[]', 'total_cost[]');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    if($count($_GET[$field] !== $length) {
        die('Not all product arrays are the same length');
    }
}


for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $message .= 'Your order information: ' . '<br />';
    $message .= 'Product ID: ' . $_GET['product_id[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Brand: '. $_GET['brand[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Model: ' . $_GET['model[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Price per item: ' . $_GET['price[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Amount of item: ' . $_GET['amount[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Total cost: ' . $_GET['total_cost[]'][$i] . '<br />' .
                'Order date and time: ' . $date. '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. When you have `brand 1` field you have to access it as `$_GET['brand_1']`. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php for more details. It's stupid, but hey, it's PHP.

Comment: @GlitchMr Well, you learn something every day, don't you. Now, I'm trying to think of what 90s reason there was for PHP4 to do this and why it hasn't been deprecated yet. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: While you are right about collecting GET/POST variables into an array, if ever the key isn't specified with a blank answer your indexes will no longer match. Also, you can have PHP build an associative array for you anyway by specifying: `product[0][id]` and `product[0][brand]`... etc.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: As far I know, it was done so you could access variables like `screenshot.x` (`<input type="image">`) when using `register_globals`. And PHP internals are hacky...

Comment: @GlitchMr You're absolutely right. This probably dates back to register globals. The underscores and other invalid characters would have to become underscores to be used as a valid PHP variable. Very good deducing! +1 to you sir

Comment: @RobertK That's why I included a check to make sure they are all the same length. If you wished to be more thorough, a check to ensure that all fields are filled would probably be advisable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [string interpolation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), or concatenation to get what you're after.

You can use either:

```
$brand = $_GET["Brand_{$i}"];
```

or:

```
$brand = $_GET['Brand_' . $i];
```

Within a for-loop to walk through each order.

You can also use a built-in feature of PHP to create an array of the products automatically. In PHP, when a form is submitted with a field named `fieldName[]` the values get transformed into an array. But, if you need to skip a value in one column, in this manner, it won't do it. However, you can specify an index, `fieldName[1]`, and so work around that trouble (do start at 0 for your indexes though, else you may need a for-each loop instead). You can also use the syntax `products[0][brand]` and get an array like:

```
$_GET['products'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'brand' => 'My Brand',
    'sku' => '0123asd'
  )
);
```

Comment: $brand = $_GET['Brand_' . $i];
Undefined variable: i
Undefined index: Brand_

Comment: @F4LLCON You need to put the code from the first two snippets within a [for-loop](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) that goes over all the entries: `for($i = 0, $count = intval($_GET['NumberOrdered']); $i < $count; $i++ { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short - you can send multiple brands under same input name. ;)

html:

```
<input name="Brand[]" value="Cat" />
<input name="Brand[]" value="Dog" />
<input name="Brand[]" value="Shuttle" />
```

php:

```
foreach($_GET['Brand'] as $brand) {
    echo $brand;
}
```

result:

```
CatDogShuttle
```

Comment: There is 1 issue: if he ever omits a brand and tracks another column the same way the indexes will no longer match. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11083728/24950) (at the bottom) for details on how to work around this to our benefit.

Comment: Undefined index: Brand
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
long story short, does not work :P